# Dynamic PHP / MYSQLi Pagination

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to make pagination work on my site dynamically and I'm not sure how to change regular pagination to accomplish what I need to do and I was wondering if a PHP guru could help out!

Basically, once a week a report runs and populates records for the last week in my database. Also, at the end of the month, the report runs and pulls in the last month of data.

I would like to build my PHP page so that all items in the same month (~4-5 weeklies and 1 monthly) show up on the same page, and that each pagination page is a different month's data.

Currently the weeks are stored as two fields, start and end date, in the format:  2018-mm-dd.

How could I have it so that page 1 is all 2018-03 records, page 2 is all 2018-02 records and page 3 is all 2018-01 records? I also would like this to be automated so each newest month becomes thE new page 1.

Does this make sense? Is this possible? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: without code its hard to understand your question.

Comment: If you think of it less as pagination and more of filtering by date, it might be a little more obvious.  By default, the page shows the current month using PHP's date function.  Then the links for the next pages could have the start date passed in the url.  You need to get familiar with PHP's DateTime object so that you know how to figure the start dates.  Then it's just a matter of crafting the query.  Easy Peasy.

Comment: Would you happen to have some good sample code that I can look at for this?

Comment: I got it working with your help!! I have no idea how to mark this solved or anything though.